# Get Device ID or unique identifier for mobile apps

Tags: php, android, jquery, ios, mobile

I've build some mobile apps for iOS and Android.

Theses apps load webpages (url are loaded in the mobile application) when you click on icons tab.

Is there a way in php or js to get a unique identifier, in order to know how many new apps are installed in real time?

EDIT: I want to know if there is a way on php/js to do this without modifying the mobile apps, so it's not a duplicate of some questions already posted.

Comment: No duplicate because my question is more related to php/js side without modifying the mobile apps. And also I need IOS and Android.

Comment: Then i don't understand the question

Comment: I want to clarify: Without considering iOS or Android (or even Windows and others), you want to create a unique identifier *from* PHP/JS? Possibly, [PHP's `uniqid`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript)?

Comment: @AndrewT. will it be possible to create a unique id per mobile application ? Like each time the user open the mobile application, the webpage loaded will always have the same uniqid ?

Comment: I'm not sure since I'm not an expert in web app, but I think it's possible. You have to define a web service to generate unique ID first, then let the app consume it once. Then, save the ID persistently inside the app. Whenever you call the web app using URL, pass the stored ID. At least that's what I think.

Comment: Ok so I have at least to modify the app to save the unique id . I will check how to proceed, thanks.